# Problem measuring local reflectance through objective lens

Tags: optics, reflection, research-level, fiber-optics

Measuring the reflectance of copper substrates using only reflection probes gives an expected reflectance (orange plot). But when an objective lens is used to focus the incident light, I can see the feature of Cu reflectance, but there is always this reflectance response that happens between 500nm and 900nm (blue plot). A reflectance standard substrate is used for calibration before taking actual measurements.

I would appreciate it if anyone could provide some insights into this problem and how I could solve it. Thanks!

[image: Left: Reflectance Setup, Top Right: Reflection Probe Configuration, Bottom Right: Result of Cu Reflectance with (blue) and without Obj Lens (orange)]

Comment: Which wavelengths are absorbed by the substance of which the lens is made?

Comment: To follow up on @Farcher " Did your calibration runs include the lens when using the standard reference?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your objective lens is only coated for visible wavelengths. The manufacturer usually provides a transmission curve for an objective. You can multiply such a curve with your orange curve and that should match your blue curve